# Valgrind Scandir Leak

Tags: c

so I'm learning how to use Valgrind and I fixed some memory errors so far. However, there is one last "definitely lost" error I'm getting. The Valgrind trace is shown below.

```
==91890== 56 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 17 of 38
==91890==    at 0x100112995: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-e0af3eb/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==91890==    by 0x100397485: scandir$INODE64 (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==91890==    by 0x100001393: numFiles (loadDoc.c:29)
==91890==    by 0x100000A23: executeParsing (indexer.c:48)
==91890==    by 0x100000931: main (indexer.c:27)
==91890==
==91890== LEAK SUMMARY:
==91890==    definitely lost: 56 bytes in 2 blocks
==91890==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==91890==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==91890==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==91890==         suppressed: 17,477 bytes in 159 blocks
```

The "numFiles" function is simply counting the number of files are in the directory. It primarily uses the scandir function whose functionality I basically got from the manpage:

```
int numFiles(char* directory) {
        struct dirent **namelist;
        int n;
        n = scandir(directory, &namelist, NULL, alphasort);
        int num_files = 0 ;
        if (n == -1) {
                perror("scandir could not be allocated\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        while (n--) {
                if ((strcmp(namelist[n]->d_name,".") == 0) 
                        || (strcmp(namelist[n]->d_name,"..") == 0)) 
                    continue;

                ++num_files;
                free(namelist[n]);
        }
        free(namelist);
        return num_files;
}
```

From what I understand, it seems that there is some memory loss with scandir and its malloc'ed memory even though I should have freed it. I'm using a MacOS Catalina if that matters. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Where do you free "." and ".."?

Comment: ah gotcha Antti thank you I didn't catch that.